# Extract sender's email address from Outlook Exchange in Python using win32

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to extract the sender's email address from outlook 2013 using win32 package in python. There are two kinds of email address type in my Inbox, exchange and smtp. If I try to print the the sender's email address of Exchange type, I am getting this:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=6F467C825619482293F429C0BDE6F1DB-
```

I have already gone through this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx) but couldn't find a function through which I can extract the smtp address.

Below is my code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders
for msg in all_inbox:
   print msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

Currently all the Email Address are coming like this:

```
/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP(FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=6F467C825619482293F429C0BDE6F1DB-
```

I found a solution to this in VB.net [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193757/how-do-i-get-the-real-email-address-with-exchange-web-services) but don't know how to rewrite the same thing in Python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, your code will fail if you have an item other than `MailItem` in the folder, such as `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem`, etc. You need to check that the `Class` property (exposed by all Outlook objects) is 43 (`olMail`).

Secondly, you need to check the sender email address type and use the `SenderEmailAddress` property only for the "SMTP" address type. In VB:

```
 for each msg in all_inbox
   if msg.Class = 43 Then
     if msg.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
       print msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
     Else
       print msg.SenderEmailAddress 
     End If  
   End If
 next
```

Comment: Thanks brother :) you saved so much of my time.

Comment: @python,  Is there anyway to extract the email signature alone from the body of the email??

Comment: @Pravin - no, signature is just a part of the HTML body, especially on incoming messages. There is nothing special about it.

Answer (score 12):

I am just modifying the program given above in Python.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders

for msg in all_inbox:
       if msg.Class==43:
           if msg.SenderEmailType=='EX':
               print msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
           else:
               print msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

This will print out all the sender's email address in your inbox folders only.

Comment: In my case, this failed with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PrimarySmtpAddress'`. How can there be no PrimarySmtpAddres?

Comment: Most probably, your folder is not containing any emails at the time of testing.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem workin with win32com today. I found the solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getexchangedistributionlist).

Using your example it would be:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders

for msg in all_inbox:
   if msg.Class==43:
       if msg.SenderEmailType=='EX':
           if msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser() != None:
               print msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
           else:
               print msg.Sender.GetExchangeDistributionList().PrimarySmtpAddress
       else:
           print msg.SenderEmailAddress
```

This should solve the group mail issue.