# Wincom32 Safetly Restrict email in group outlook before searching on subject

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

I have the following Python code which loops through emails in a group shared outlook mailbox and then saves attachments. However this will do a scan of the entire inbox.

I have seen in other answers that this is understandably a terrible idea although the third answer isn't clear to me how to go about it:

[Extract sender's email address from Outlook Exchange in Python using win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619012/extract-senders-email-address-from-outlook-exchange-in-python-using-win32) .

I wish to restrict the inbox to only emails sent by a specific person with keywords in the subject. My pseudo-code is below which i have been working on today

```
# new outlook object
import win32com.client as win32com
outlook = win32com.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders.Item("group@foo.com").Folders.Item("Inbox")

# Here we apply the filter above and then print out the attachment name
# After the file is downloaded we mark the mail as read
Items = inbox.Items
for item in Items:
    
# Check if the item is unread and has the desired sender and subject
    if item.UnRead and item.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress == "foo@foo.com" and item.subject.contains("FM1, Football, results"):
        # Loop through all the attachments in the item
        for attachment in item.Attachments:
            try:
                save_path = (os.getcwd() + "\\email_attachments\\" +
                             attachment.FileName)

                # Save the File and mark the email as unread
                attachment.SaveAsFile(save_path)
                item.UnRead = False

            except:
                print('Error:', attachment.FileName)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39634217/4539709

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44124028/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *on the right avenue* - use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class, they allow getting items that correspond to the specified search criteria only. You can read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

DASL supports the matching of prefixes, phrases, and substrings in a string property using content indexer keywords `ci_startswith` and `ci_phrasematch`, and the keyword `like`. If a store is indexed, searching with content indexer keywords is more efficient than with like. If your search scenarios include substring matching (which content indexer keywords don't support), use the `like` keyword in a DASL query. For example, to search items with a specific keyword in the Subject line you can use the following search criteria string (VBA syntax):

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'question'"
```

where `Chr` is the VBA function and returns the character from the ASCII table. For example, `Chr(34)` returns the 34th character, which is the `“` sign.

> I wish to restrict the inbox to only emails sent by a specific person with keywords in the subject.

You may combine conditions using AND keyword in the search string.

To search for items. For example, to search for items from a specific email address you can use:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'eugene@test.com'"
```

Answer (score 2):

*Here is quick example with multiple filters*

```
import win32com.client

def outlook_emails(Inbox):    
    Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail" +
                        chr(34) + "ci_phrasematch '%0m3r@email.com%' AND " +
                        chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" +
                        chr(34) + "=1 AND " +
                        chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:read" +
                        chr(34) + "=0")


    items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    print(items.Count)

    for item in items:
        print(item.Subject)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        "outlook.Application").GetNamespace(
        "MAPI")

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    outlook_emails(inbox)
```